# data not updated straight away at profile page after navigate from edit profile page instead need to go homepage first

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cubit

the problem here is whenever the data being edit and updated at my details page, when user navigate back to previous page which is profile page, the data not straight away updated. instead, user need to navigate back to homepage then enter profile page back to fetch the latest data.

i have tried to construct the Bloc cubit properly with ChatGPT help and implement the `refreshIndicator()` but both didn't  work. I was thinking maybe the navigation is not right? but im not sure how to debug this. it just kind of bad user experience. is it because im using 2 bloc provider? first at main page and second at profile tab bar page. below is the snippet code on how i construct the Bloc.

any kind of help is really appreaciated. thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want the data to remain synced throughout the app, there should be only one instance of `ProfileContentCubit` created.

From the code you sent, I saw you had created two `ProfileContentCubit`, which apparently have different states. What you update within the detail pages affects the 2nd cubit, while from the profile page, data is rendered according to 1st cubit's state.

### How to fix it

#### Solution 1

Define `ProfileContentCubit` inside `BlocProvider` inside `main.dart`, the biggest scope, so that from anywhere can access `ProfileContentCubit`.

#### Solution 2

Get to know about `BlocProvider` and `BlocProvider.value`:
`BlocProvider` practically creates new Bloc by using function assigned to `create`,
While `BlocProvider.value` only repropagates existing blocs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. i currently apply for the solution 1. the problem here is i need to use the blocprovider.value for all three page and i always get this error on my details page thats why i added the blocprovider at profile tab bar page.
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a ProfileContentCubit.
The relevant error-causing widget was:

Comment: nope, please watch this tutorial about bloc inside navigation route: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laqnY0NjU3M&list=PLptHs0ZDJKt_T-oNj_6Q98v-tBnVf-S_o&index=7